# Opening .xul links in a new browser window

Tags: firefox, hyperlink, firefox-addon, xul

I have installed a FF extension called FireSSH which is basically a terminal in Firefox. When it runs the URL in the address bar is chrome://firessh/content/firessh.xul - I would like to make a link on a webpage that will open FireSSH but all atempts thus far have failed, for example I have tried:

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
window.open("chrome://firessh/content/firessh.xul");
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">firessh></a>
```

and also:

```
<a href="gBrowser.addTab("chrome://firessh/content/firessh.xul#account=Russell");">firessh</a>
```

and simply:

```
<a href="chrome://firessh/content/firessh.xul#account=Russel">firessh</a>
```

Any help appreciated.

B.

Answer (score 1):

listen to all pages and when you find pages of interest, from your addon do,

```
var link = gBrowser.contentDocument.querySelector('#myLink');
link.addEventListener('click',openXulWindow,false);

//this openXulWindow opens a regular browser window
    function openXulWindow() {
    var sa = Cc["@mozilla.org/supports-array;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsISupportsArray);
    var wuri = Cc["@mozilla.org/supports-string;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsISupportsString);
    wuri.data = 'http://www.bing.com/';
    let aCharset = 'UTF-8';
    let charset = Cc["@mozilla.org/supports-string;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsISupportsString);
    charset.data = "charset=" + aCharset;
    var aAllowThirdPartyFixup = false;
    var allowThirdPartyFixupSupports = Cc["@mozilla.org/supports-PRBool;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsISupportsPRBool);
    allowThirdPartyFixupSupports.data = aAllowThirdPartyFixup;
    sa.AppendElement(wuri);
    sa.AppendElement(charset);
    sa.AppendElement(allowThirdPartyFixupSupports);
    let features = "chrome,dialog=no,all";
    if (PrivateBrowsingUtils.permanentPrivateBrowsing) {
       features += ",private";
    } else {
       features += ",non-private";
    }
    Services.ww.openWindow(null, 'chrome://browser/content/browser.xul', null, features, sa);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Web content is not allowed to access, link and/or script `chrome:` content due to security concerns. `chrome:` runs at a higher security level, and allowing web content to unrestrictedly *call* into `chrome:` would essentially be a privilege escalation vulnerability.